# Limiting WebAPI Newtonsoft JSON.NET maximum response size

Tags: c#, json, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api, json.net

I have a large WebAPI configured that is using Newtonsoft JSON.NET serializer to return JSON to the client.

Sometimes the responses can be really large (>100mb) which can cause browsers to crash. Instead of returning these large results, I'd prefer to handle it by throwing an exception or taking some other action. I cannot find a way to detect this situation.

The first thing I tried was adding this to my `Web.Config` file:

```
<system.web.extensions>
           <scripting>
               <webServices>
                   <jsonSerialization maxJsonLength="50000000"/>
               </webServices>
           </scripting>
 </system.web.extensions>
```

However, it appears this setting only applies to MVC and has no effect on WebAPI nor Newtonsoft.

Next I tried reading the `ContentLength` from the header in ExecuteAsync with something like this:

```
        public override Task<HttpResponseMessage> ExecuteAsync(System.Web.Http.Controllers.HttpControllerContext controllerContext, System.Threading.CancellationToken cancellationToken)
        {
            Task<HttpResponseMessage> task = base.ExecuteAsync(controllerContext, cancellationToken);
            task.GetAwaiter().OnCompleted(() =>
            {
                if (task.Status == TaskStatus.RanToCompletion)
                {

                    // Check the size.
                    long? resultLength = task.Result.Content.Headers.ContentLength;

                    // This is always 0.
               }
            });

            return task;
        }
```

But the value is always 0.

I noticed this post about potentially using a `DelegatingHandler`:
[Capture the size of the response (in bytes) of a WebAPI method call](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21934933/capture-the-size-of-the-response-in-bytes-of-a-webapi-method-call)

But I really dislike the idea of loading the entire buffer into memory before sending it to the client.

Is there really no way to do this properly? Seems weird.

Comment: Small clarification...the jsonSerialization setting should be affecting the *default* JsonSerializer which MVC uses, whereas WebAPI uses Newtonsoft.  So no, that wouldn't affect it unless Newtonsoft specifically wrote something to look for it.

Comment: @DavidL thanks! I didn't know that, just assumed it didn't apply to WebAPI at all (I haven't seen any examples on the web saying it worked for them with WebAPI).